# React-Native Debugger Not working after user Login

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-debugger

Recently, I found one issue while trying to debug my React native app. I noticed that the debugger and react-native debugger worked fine before the user was authenticated using Firebase authentication. However, as soon as the user logged in, the screen was blocked, and I could no longer debug or use the app. It crashed, and nothing worked until I turned off the debugger.

1. Enable / disable hermes does not help me.

Environment:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.3.1
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Memory: 90.75 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 20.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 9.8.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.09.04.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
    Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.17 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
    react-native: 0.71.2 => 0.71.2 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```